# Button being cut off by mat-step element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, styling

**Problem Statement**

My button is being cut off by the `mat-step` element or so it seems.

---

**What I've Tried**

- I played around with the padding and margins of the `mat-step` element and it doesn't work.
- I played around with the positioning and it doesn't work.
- I played with the `z-index` but to no avail.

---

**Picture of Problem**

[image]

---

**Explanation of Picture**

As you can see, the next button is being cut off by the `mat-step` element, and I made sure that the problem is the `mat-step`. I did this by making the background of the stepper grey and found that it adjusts just fine. I made the `mat-step` grey, but nothing showed up, and it doesn't adjust with any CSS. There is clearly something wrong with the `mat-step`.

---

**My Code**

**CSS**

```
.stepper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.stepBtns {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20pt;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper class="stepper">
    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <mat-step>

      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- Step 2 -->
    <mat-step>

      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- Step 3 -->
    <mat-step>

      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- Step 4 -->
    <mat-step>

      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- Step 5 -->
    <mat-step>

      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button class="stepBtns" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>

  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

---

**Expected Results**

I want to button to function normally and to be seen completely.

---

**Actual Results**

The button is being cut off by the `mat-step`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the use of relative position (and top styling). You will either need to work around these settings or, preferably, remove them all together.

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-program-jgsasc

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't help. The reason is that I want to move my buttons down and center because I will be placing content inside the step (which the buttons are in the way of).

Comment: @Compilerv2 I've updated the stackblitz to show how to add content to a step and how the buttons adjust accordingly.